# in eclipse plug-in, programmatically save new .java files to an existing jar file in the workspace

Tags: java, jar, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a plug-in for `Eclipse Standard/SDK` Kepler to give diagnostic feedback to undergraduate student programmers as they work on their Java programming assignments. The student can run my plug-in as often as he wishes to see if his code triggers any messages about poor programming practices he might want to change.

Each time the student invokes the plug-in, I need to save a copy of all the .java files in the student's project as well as a text file containing the diagnostic feedback produced by the plug-in.  I don't want to make the student use a file export wizard, so I figured out how to programmatically create a jar file using the `JarPackageData` and `JarWriter3` classes from `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.jarpackager`.  That works for the first time I save files, but I don't want to create a new jar each time the student runs the plug-in.  When the student runs my plug-in for the second (third, fourth…) time I want to add more files to the jar I already made so that I end up with a single jar file that contains a complete record of the student's use of my plug-in.

`JarWriter3` creates a new jar file but does not provide any methods to add to a jar that already exists.  I have searched both the Eclipse documentation and the stackoverflow archive, so far without success.  One answer to a previous question explained how to write a jar file using the `java.util.jar.JarEntry` and `JarOutputStream` classes, but I thought I should stick with functionality provided by Eclipse classes if indeed there are any that will solve my problem.

Comment: what you do till ?? try any code ??

Answer (score 1):

`JarWriter3` is essentially just a fairly thin wrapper around `JarOutputStream`, for example the constructor opens the jar output stream with:

```
if (fJarPackage.usesManifest() && fJarPackage.areGeneratedFilesExported()) {
  Manifest manifest = fJarPackage.getManifestProvider().create(fJarPackage);
  fJarOutputStream = new JarOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fJarPackage.getAbsoluteJarLocation().toFile())), manifest);
} else
  fJarOutputStream = new JarOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fJarPackage.getAbsoluteJarLocation().toFile())));
```

so I would be inclined to just use the standard Java `JarOutputStream` and `JarEntry`.

If you are saving the jar in the workspace you will need to call `IFile.refreshLocal` once the jar is written to get it recognised by Eclipse.